# What is the equivalent syntax of this line of code(myMovie->pMovieTitle->pValue) using the * and . operators?

Tags: c

```
struct Values {
char *pValue;   //character string
int nBytes; //amount of bytes
};

struct Movie {
Values *pMovieTitle;    //Name of Movie
};

Movie *myMovie;
```

**1) What is the equivalent syntax of this line of code using the * and . operators?**

```
myMovie->pMovieTitle->pValue;
```

I tried

```
(*myMovie).pMovieTitle->pValue
```

which works, however

```
(*myMovie).(*pMovieTitle).pValue
```

Doesn't work.

**2) Why are there two arrow operators when there are three pointers?  myMovie, pMovieTitle and pValue are all pointers.**

For example there are two arrow operators for this line of code:

```
myMovie->pMovieTitle->pValue;
```

and there are two arrow operators for this line of code:

```
myMovie->pMovieTitle->nBytes;
```

Even though pValue is a pointer and nBytes is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your second attempt should be `(*(*myMovie).pMovieTitle).pvalue`; you can't dereference a struct member, only the value returned after accessing said member.
2. The fact that `pValue` is a pointer is irrelevant; `->` is used when the object on the left is a struct pointer, regardless of the type of the member named on the right.

Answer (score 1):

1. `(*((*myMovie).pMovieTitle)).pValue`
2. It doesn't matter if pValue is a pointer you aren't dereferencing it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Because I think you have to do something like :

```
 (*((*myMovie).pMovieTitle)).pValue
```